# Не отображаются спрайты в game. Unity 2D

Tags: unity3d

Объекты генерируются на сцене, но в game их не видно.
Первый скрин - параметры камеры, на втором - сцена, на третьем game и координаты спрайта, который создается.
Думаю что ошибка как раз с осями, но вот где, не понимаю[image: Камера]

[image: Это данные со сцены][[image: Координаты спрайта и gameИ камера]

Comment: Если уже у созданных объектов меняю координату z, то спрайт видно в game. Как сделать, чтобы объект не перемещался по этой оси?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй в настройках спрайта в альфа канале 1 поставить, возможно поможет)

Comment: А где находится этот альфа канал?